# how to check condition if temp data has value in every controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization

I am looking for the optimized way of checking if tempdata has value or not in every controller in MVC. I don't want to write in every controller, Where can I write this condition that if temp data has value then show the view else redirect to Login page.

Comment: You could write an `ActionFilter` to check the value and do a redirect, but the fact you you want to redirect to a Login page based on a value in `TempData` suggests a major problem with the design of your app.

Comment: I think its a bad practice to move the value of TempData on every page and keep on checking it like you have to use KEEP,PEEK every time.So try to avoid it in use more

Comment: My scenario is I am storing userid in tempdata after user logins into the application, it gets null if I leave my website for some time (which I am trying to figure it out), I need to check if userid is not null then the view should be displayed else it should take to login page.

Comment: Yes its a bad practice but its being used in overall application, I did not write this approach there was another deveoper who used this. I cant change it right now.

Comment: Then why not use the `[Authorize]` Attribute? This is exactly what `Authorize` does.

Comment: `[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 ....
} `
I put this on every controller class, should I add to every action ?

Comment: Asp.net mvc [Authorize] attribute is another cool feature that makes it easy to add authentication at the Controller level.

Comment: add this on on every action ?

Comment: You can put it on every action or just on the controller level which will apply it on all of the actions on that controller. How does you authenticate your users?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please create a base controller

   ```
   public class BaseController : Controller
   {
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       var id = filterContext.Controller.TempData["id"];
       if (id == null)
       {
           filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       }
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
     }
    }
   ```
2. After that you have to inherit the base controller on very controller.

   ```
   public class CheckController : BaseController
   {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
       TempData["id"] = 2;

       return View();
      }
     }
   ```

Comment: Okay let me try this solution

Comment: Don't be lazy - format your code so that we can read it better!

Comment: are you sure  `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);` is outside the function ?

Comment: I added the line in the function and its not redirecting =S

Comment: It will be inside the function, please see above updated answer

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer?, if it is not working please provide your full code controller and BaseController.

Comment: Sorry i modified my code, its working perfect ! Thank you so much.

Comment: yes I also removed the `ReturnUrl` part and now its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use base controller in every controller. Then check in base controller that if temp data has value then show the view else redirect to Login page.

Comment: Can you give me an example link ? I was thinking about this approach

Comment: Add a controller name BaseController
and Then like this.
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
}

Do your operation in base controller

Comment: I know how to do this inheritance, needed the code to override the default behavior I tried Banwari Yadav soution,

Answer (score -1):

Filter code:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("some key", "some value");
    }
}
```

Action code:

```
[MyCustom]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    string value = TempData["key"] as string;
    return View();
}
```